# Textbox for image map

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a textbox with some additional information when hovering over my image map.
Does anyone have an idea how that could work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>
function writeText(txt) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src ="test.png" alt="Jacket" usemap="#jacket" />

<p id="test"></p>
<map name="jacket">
    <area shape="poly" coords="174,361,149,350,180,203,217,213"href="test"; title="Discover" alt="Shop Now" onmouseover="writeText('$60')" />
  <map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area href="test"; title="Shop Now" alt="Discover" shape="poly" coords="221,215,183,218,190,164" onmouseover="writeText('$60')" onmouseout="writeText('')"/>
</map> 
</map> 

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks everyone. I ended up doing something like this

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
     $('area').qtip({
        style: {
            classes: 'qtip-dark'
        },
         content: 'Shop Now!',
         position: {
             target: 'mouse', // Track the mouse as the positioning target
             adjust: { x: 5, y: 5 } // Offset it slightly from under the mouse
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: It is called tooltip. There is a huge number of scripts for that. For example - http://qtip2.com/demos

Comment: Yes, I saw the qtip2. I tried to implement their anchor tooltip to mouse but I have trouble linking it to my map

Comment: try do like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510686/tooltip-on-map-area-tag

Comment: Thanks both of you I was able to figure it out